# If $H^i(\tilde{X}, \mathcal{F}) = 0$, then is it true that $H^i(X, \mathcal{F}) = 0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a nonsingular variety over $\mathbb{C}$, and
let $\pi : \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$  be a blowing up of some codimension 2 set.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$.

> If $H^i(\tilde{X}, \mathcal{F}) = 0$, then is it true in general that $H^i(X, \mathcal{F}) = 0$?
>   Or, when is it true?

Of course, it is true for $\mathcal{O}_X$ because $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is birational invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you are asking for (since $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf on $X$, not $\tilde{X}$), but here is a partial answer:

**Proposition.** *Let $X$ be a nonsingular variety over $\mathbf{C}$, and let $f\colon Y \to X$ be a proper birational morphism. Then, for every locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{E}$ of finite rank and every integer $i \ge 0$, we have*
$$H^i(X,\mathscr{E}) \simeq H^i(Y,f^*\mathscr{E}).$$

*Proof.* Recall the Leray spectral sequence [[Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu), [Tag 01F2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01F2)], which says that for an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module $\mathscr{F}$, there is a spectral sequence
$$E_2^{pq} = H^p(X,R^qf_*\mathscr{F}) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(Y,\mathscr{F}).$$
If $\mathscr{E}$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite rank, then setting $\mathscr{F} = f^*\mathscr{E}$ in the spectral sequence above, we have
$$E_2^{pq} = H^p(X,\mathscr{E} \otimes R^qf_*\mathcal{O}_X) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(Y,f^*\mathscr{E}).$$
But by a theorem of Hironaka [[Hironaka](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970486), Ch. 0, §7, Cor. 2], we have that $R^qf_*\mathcal{O}_X = 0$ for all $q > 0$, hence the spectral sequence degenerates, and we have the desired isomorphism. $\blacksquare$

This statement is moreover true when $X$ and $Y$ are schemes which are only assumed to have pseudo-rational singularities by [[Kovács](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02269v5), Cor. 9.19].